# How could checking again if result is false lead to more false results?

Tags: c++

I am checking point in rectangle. I can't understand how adding the (Check number 2 if statement in the below code) cause the code to result in more false returns than without it. Could someone please help me understand this code  behavior.

I was expecting adding this if statement to either have the same number of false returns or less.

```
    if (p.x <= center.x + halfWidth && p.x >= center.x - halfWidth
        && p.y <= center.y + halfHeight && p.y >= center.y - halfHeight)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {


        //Check number # 2
        if ( ( (p.x <= center.x + halfWidth && p.x >= center.x - halfWidth)
            || (p.x - center.x + halfWidth < 0.0001)||(p.x - center.x - halfWidth) <  0.0001)

            && ((p.y <= center.y + halfHeight && p.y >= center.y - halfHeight)
            || p.y - center.y + halfHeight <  0.0001 || p.y - center.y - halfHeight <  0.0001))
        {

            return true;
        }


        return false; 
    }
```

Please ignore that I am using (0.0001) instead of epsilon

Comment: Use your debugger to see where the change comes from

Comment: Does the number of "true" returns in you function affect how many times the checking function is called, by any chance?

Comment: can you include the data you use for testing? is this function used recursively and does the output change the p values?  it's strange that it should return more false with Check#2 since Check#1 is redundant, because 
(A || C) && (B || D) in check #1 will cover the case of A && B in check #2

Comment: It's alright, you'd have to use 2 * epsilom, anyway.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Somehow, you must be mis-interpreting the behavior you observe. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: Thank you all! After tracing where the change comes from it turned out that the added part changed the point path which changed the list of rects against which it is being tested. The change in "false/true" count comes from the overall code behavior. Sorry it is my mistake. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to work with edges instead of the centerpoint?

```
float left = center.x - halfWidth;    // halfWidth??
float right = center.x + halfWith;    // having rect defined this way
float top = center.y + halfHeight;    // adds 1 * FLT_EPSILOM error
float bottom = center.y - halfHeight; // to all calculus ops.

float error_x = fabs(p.x * 2 * FLT_EPSILOM);
float error_y = fabs(p.y * 2 * FLT_EPSILOM);

return (left <= (p.x + error_x) && (p.x - error_x) <= right)
    && (bottom <= (p.y + error_y) && (p.y - error_y) <= top);
```

Comment: Thanks! It is much cleaner, I will use it.